# Delete from sql with no refreshing page not working when loading with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have chat and i am loading these by `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "chat/mini.php",
    success: function(chat){
        $('.chat-message').html(chat);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

And i Have in `chat/mini.php` link to delete

```
<a href="#" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="delbutton text-danger" title="Delete">X</a>
```

and script

```
$(".delbutton").click(function () {

    //Save the link in a variable called element
    var element = $(this);

    //Find the id of the link that was clicked
    var del_id = element.attr("id");

    //Built a url to send
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
    if (confirm("Sure you want to delete? There is NO undo!")) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "chat/delete.php",
            data: info,
            success: function () {

            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

And these cod working when i not loading chat with `ajax` but when i loading these with `ajax` these don't working. I must add something to work?

Comment: change `$(".delbutton").click(function () {` to `$(".delbutton").on('click',function () {`

Comment: Reason did you checked what i tell?

Comment: Yes i check but don't working

Comment: Since the html(the one returned by chat/mini.php) is dynamic, when handling events for html elements that are created dynamically you should use jquery delegating. You can do it the old way and call the [delegate method])(http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or $(".chat-message").on('click', '.delbutton', function() {});

Comment: Ty its working now